# Mapping an state array in React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native

[image]I am trying to map through the array that was stored in the state. The arrray had datas from firebase. I did console.log to see the what the state contains and it has the values but just not mapping it.

```
render() {
    let test = this.state.subjects.map(sub => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{sub}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
    return <ScrollView style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>{test}</ScrollView>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to log `sub` in the console.

Comment: @MahediSabuj nothing shows

Comment: Can you show us the value of `this.state.subjects`?

Comment: [
0: "This is a test 2"
1: "This is a test"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
]

Comment: I added a picture of the console result

Comment: Its the state variable that is not mapping, I tried regular variable inside render it did map but I need to map the state variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pushing the data directly to the state variable. But according to react native docs you should never do that and use ‘this.state.setState’ method.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code:

```
renderSub() {
    return this.state.sub.map((value, index) => {
        return (
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{sub}</Text>
        )
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderSub()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as you get an `Object` from firebase you have to convert it to an `typeof Array` to map over it - so you could do something like

```
Object.values(this.state.subjects).map(...)
```

Comment: the data is pushed in the state array

Comment: [
0: "This is a test 2"
1: "This is a test"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use React-Native **FlatList** to show the values of array.

See the Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist